# Using subclass implementation in the definition of superclass functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, subclass, typeclass, class-hierarchy

In my Haskell program I have some typeclasses representing abstract notions of "shapes", namely

```
-- | Class representing shapes.
class Shape a where
  isColliding :: (Shape b) => a -> b -> Bool
  centroid :: Point

-- | Class representing shapes composed of a finite number of vertices 
and line segments connecting them.
class (Shape a) => Polygon a where
  vertices :: a -> Vertices
```

As you can see, `Polygon` is naturally a subclass of `Shape`. I also have some data types that are instances of these different typeclasses. For example:

```
data Box = Box Point Point Angle

instance Shape Box where
  ...

instance Polygon Box where
  ...

---------------------------------

data Circle = Circle Point Radius

instance Shape Circle where
  ...
```

I have many more possible shapes, such as `NGon`, `RegularNGon`, etc. I would like to be able to implement `isColliding`, but the information required to calculate whether two shapes are colliding is dependent upon the implementation of the specific instance of `Shape`. For example, to calculate if two boxes are colliding, I need their list of vertices. So I have a few questions:

1. Is there anyway to "specialize" my function `isColliding` so that it is defined in a specific way for collisions of the type `isColliding :: (Polygon b) => Box -> b -> Bool`?
2. Is the structuring of my datatypes the best way to approach this problem, or am I misusing typeclasses and datatypes when the whole thing could be restructured to eliminate this problem?

I am rather new to Haskell, so if my question is worded poorly or any clarification is needed, please tell me.

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could have two function; `isCollidingShape` in the `Shape` class and `isCollidingPolygon` in the `Polygon` class, and a default implementation of `isCollidingShape = isCollidingPolygon` for those `Shape`s which are also `Polygon`s. Generally, this isn't really a correct way to design interfaces - you've begun with the interface and hope it is sufficient to implement a certain functionality; instead you should begin by trying to implement that functionality for some concrete cases, and then abstract similar functionality into an interface.

Comment: Object-oriented inheritance is often more naturally represented as a sum type. (The term "class" can mislead – in OOP, you're classifying objects; in Haskell, you're classifying types.)

Comment: "Object-oriented inheritance is often more naturally represented as a sum type". I keep wondering where people are getting this strange idea from. There is literally nothing in common between them. BTW a classification on types naturally induces a classification on objects. @molbdnilo

Answer (score 10):

Your current `Shape` class says “`isColliding` can tell whether this shape intersects another shape *using only the methods of `Shape`* on the other shape”, because its signature `(Shape b) => a -> b -> Bool` only tells you that `b` has an instance of `Shape`. So you’re right that this isn’t quite what you want.

One thing you can do is use `MultiParamTypeClasses` to describe a *relationship* between two types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Colliding a b where
  collidesWith :: a -> b -> Bool
```

And then make instances for various concrete combinations of types:

```
instance Colliding Circle Box where
  Circle p r `collidesWith` Box p1 p2 θ = {- … -}
```

Here you know the concrete types of both `a` and `b` when defining the implementation. That might be good enough for your use case.

However, this leaves you with *n*<sup>2</sup> instances if you have *n* types. And you’ll run into problems if you try to define polymorphic instances like this:

```
instance (HasBoundingBox b) => Colliding Circle b where
  collidesWith = {- … -}
```

Because this *overlaps* with all your other instances for `Colliding Circle`: `b` will match *any* type, and only add the constraint that `b` must have an instance of `HasBoundingBox`. That constraint is checked *after* instance resolution. You can work around this with `OverlappingInstances` or the newer `OVERLAPPABLE`/`OVERLAPPING`/`OVERLAPS` pragmas to tell GHC to choose the *most specific* matching instance, but this might be more trouble than it’s worth if you’re just getting familiar with Haskell.

I’d have to think on it more, but there are definitely alternative approaches. In the simplest case, if you only need to deal with a few different kinds of shape, then you can just make them a single sum type instead of separate data types:

```
data Shape
  = Circle Point Radius
  | Box Point Point Angle
  | …
```

Then your `isColliding` function can be of type `Shape -> Shape -> Bool` and just pattern-match on this type.

Generally speaking, if you’re writing a typeclass, it should come with *laws* for how instances should behave, like `mappend x mempty == mappend mempty x == x` from `Data.Monoid`. If you can’t think of any equations that should always hold for instances of your class, you should prefer to represent things with plain old functions and data types instead.